# Rails - NameError undefined local variable or method `conversation'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails newbie here. I am trying out this Mailboxer gem and was implementing in on my website. I want to create an inbox system but somehow its not showing me the conversations show page. It gives me the following error:

> NameError in Conversations#show Showing
>   C:/Sites/myinbox/app/views/conversations/show.html.haml where
>   line #6 raised:
>
> undefined local variable or method `conversation'

I don't where I am going wrong. I am following a tutorial [here](http://josephndungu.com/tutorials/private-inbox-system-in-rails-with-mailboxer) on how to set it up but I am not getting the conversations to show.

I would really appreciate if you'd help!

show.html.haml

```
.row
  .spacer
  .col-md-6
    = link_to "Compose", new_conversation_path, class: "btn btn-success"
  .col-md-6.text-right
    - if conversation.is_trashed?(current_user) <!-- LINE 6 -->
      = link_to 'Untrash', untrash_conversation_path(conversation), class: 'btn btn-info', method: :post
    - else
      = link_to 'Move to trash', trash_conversation_path(conversation), class: 'btn btn-danger', method: :post, |
        data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}                                                                        |
.row
  .spacer
  .col-md-4
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-body
        = render 'mailbox/folders'
  .col-md-8
    .panel.panel-default
      .panel-body
        = render partial: 'messages'
      .panel-footer
        / Reply Form
        = form_for :message, url: reply_conversation_path(conversation) do |f|
          .form-group
            = f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Reply Message", rows: 4, class: "form-control"
          = f.submit "Reply", class: 'btn btn-danger pull-right'
```

conversations_controller.rb

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
  end

  def create
    recipients = User.where(id: conversation_params[:recipients])
    conversation = current_user.send_message(recipients, conversation_params[:body], conversation_params[:subject]).conversation
    flash[:notice] = "Your message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def show
    @receipts = conversation.receipts_for(current_user).order("created_at ASC")
    # mark conversation as read
    conversation.mark_as_read(current_user)
  end


  def reply
    current_user.reply_to_conversation(conversation, message_params[:body])
    flash[:notice] = "Your reply message was successfully sent!"
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end

  def trash
    conversation.move_to_trash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end

  def untrash
    conversation.untrash(current_user)
    redirect_to mailbox_inbox_path
  end


  private

  def conversation_params
    params.require(:conversation).permit(:subject, :body,recipients:[])
  end

  def message_params
    params.require(:message).permit(:body, :subject)
  end
end
```

Comment: You need to declare `conversation` as `@conversation`. Because, views can have access only to instance variables.

Comment: The next step of this tutorial (the one creating `conversation` helper method in this controller) should help.

Answer (score 0):

The show.html.haml file cannot access conversation directly, therefore you need to create an instance variable i.e. @conversation = conversation in your show in conversations_controller.rb.

Answer (score 0):

A little more reasoning for the existing answers.

Break this down for a moment: `if conversation.is_trashed?(current_user)`:

> **if** calling the method **is_trashed** with parameter **current_user** on the variable **conversation** results in a truthy value then continue

where does the variable `conversation` come from? if you think of your view as a method you'll notice something - it does not define `conversation` anywhere!

in order to allow your view to *see* variables from within your controller you have to make it an *instance variable*. in ruby this is done by prepending `@` to it (yes, it's a little bit of syntax magic - "regular" variables are visible by their enclosing methods but variables with a name starting with `@` are visible to the whole instance).

Answer (score 0):

On your application_controller.rb (app/controllers/application_controller.rb) You gotta do this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # [...]
  helper_method :mailbox, :conversation

  private
  # [...]
  def conversation
    @conversation ||= mailbox.conversations.find(params[:id])
  end

  protected
  # [...]
end
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "this"? What are the relevant parts and why do they solve the original problem?

Comment: Nameerror on the show view indicates that the conversation as an instance variable is not defined... so in other to fix that mailboxer supports you defined that method on the application controller. If u take a good look at the method it fetching the id for a specific single conversation involving the sender and the recipient.